# Selenium tests open unnescessary popups

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium

I'm running selenium test to test application. I login to application,check some UI text and log off. when i log off, current browser gets closed and one more browser opens with popup the webpage you are viewing is trying to close window.Do you want to continue.

Manually when i log off application,it redirects me to login page on same browser window.
But from seelnium tests,it closes current browser and opens another browser with popup.

I tried chooseOKonNextConfirmation method to select yes button on popup,but its not clicking.
How can i avoid generating these popups
I'm using selenium jar 2.30(RC)
IE 8 ,Windows XP

Comment: You need to tell your browser not to do this - I know the options are somewhere in the Internet Options >Security tab but I'm not sure which one....

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your test, add...

*Selenium 1 Solution:*

- use `selenium.stop();`

*Selenium 2 Solution:*

- use `webdriver.quit();`

Both of these methods will kill all open browser windows, and prevent that from happening.

Comment: Thanks for reply..But i use selenium.stop at end of test.issue is even before stop. I log off application clicking on log off button.When log off button is clicked,current browser gets closed and one more browser opens with popup "the webpage you are viewing is trying to close window.Do you want to continue?" This happens only during automation through selenium. Manually clicking on log off button redirects me to login page on same browser window

Comment: can someone tell what are the internet options?i tried with almost all options in security tab.Nothing helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Use window handles to switch the focus to pop-up windows and then use .quit() . to close the pop-up windows.